# Caesar Cipher using files

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a java program that encode a plain text using caesar cipher. I have a file which contains the plain text and another one where the encoded text should be put. I don't know whats the problem but i get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException. Please help me!

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.PrintStream;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class zevendesim {

  public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("C:\\erida\\t.txt"));
    PrintStream output=new PrintStream(new File("C:\\erida\\c.txt"));
    String text=input.nextLine();
    zevendesim(text, output);
}
public static void zevendesim(String text, PrintStream output)
{

    int i=0;
    String s;
    Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
    while (data.hasNext()) {
        s=data.next();
        if (s.charAt(i) >= 97 && s.charAt(i)<= 120)
        {
            int x = s.charAt(i) - 97;
            x = (x + 2) % 26;
            if (x < 0) 
              x += 26; 
            // = (char) (x + 32);
        }
        output.print(" " + data.next());
    }

}
}
```

Please help me find a solution!

The error stack trace is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at
>   Zevendesimi.zevendesim.zevendesim(zevendesim.java:33) at
>   Zevendesimi.zevendesim.main(zevendesim.java:15)

Comment: At least post a more detailed stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at Zevendesimi.zevendesim.zevendesim(zevendesim.java:33)
 at Zevendesimi.zevendesim.main(zevendesim.java:15)

Comment: add to the question

Comment: Why are you using Scanner to iterate over a String? Just use a For.

Comment: ok. i will try it

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in `output.print(" " + data.next());` because the last token has already been read a few lines earlier with `s=data.next();`

You probably want to write x to the output?